# does docker manage filesystem like a standalone OS?

Tags: linux, docker, local-storage, filesystems, file-not-found

I have a program I'm running in a docker container. After 10-12 hours of run, the program terminated with filesystem-related errors (FileNotFoundError, or similar).
I'm wondering if the disk space got filled up or a similar filesystem-related issue or there was a problem in my code (e.g one process deleted the file pre-maturely).
I don't know much about docker management of files and wonder if inside docker it creates and manages its own FS or not. Here are three possibilities I'm considering and mainly wonder if #1 could be the case or not.

1. If docker manages it's own filesystem, could it be that although disk space is available on the host machine, docker container ran out of it's own storage space? (I've seen similar issues regarding running out of memory for a process that has limited memory artificially imposed using cgroups)
2. Could it be that host filesystem ran out of space and the files got corrupted or maybe didn't get written correctly?
3. There is some bug in my code.

Comment: You can't (*) directly access the container filesystem that Docker manages.  It may or may not have a size limitation, depending on the host OS and specific installation.  I think you'd need to provide some more details to help understand what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bug in your code. Most programs print the error they encounter, and when a program encounters out-of-space, the error returned by the filesystem is: "No space left on device" (errno 28 `ENOSPC`).

If you see FileNotFoundError, that means the file is missing. My best theory is that it's coming from your consumer process.
It's still possible though, that the file doesn't exist because the producer ran out of space and you didn't handle the error correctly - you'll need to check your logs.
It might also be a race condition, depending on your application. There's really not enough details to answer that.

As to the title question:

By default, docker just overlay-mounts an empty directory from the host's filesystem into the container, so the amount of free space on the container is the same as the amount on the host.

If you're using volumes, that depends on the [storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-storage-driver) you use. As @Dan Serbyn mentioned, the default limit for the [devicemapper driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#devicemapper-options) is 10 GB. The overlay2 driver - the default driver - doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: My docker is apparently using overlay2 with extfs(ext4) as storage driver and backing filesystem. However seems like tmpfs is being used for running the docker in this case. I assume limiting the memory available to the container doesn't limit tmpfs which is used for storage. Is that correct assumption? If that's the case, does it mean that docker will only fail if it uses up the entire available memory on the server? Or there are other limits that might play a role? Mainly wondering if I can get a clue by checking available memory to see if it was utilized 90%+ or not at the time of failure.

Comment: BTW, Thanks a lot for sharing the info about storage driver, overlay2, and devicemapper driver. They were extremely. informative and helpful.

Comment: Unless the storage driver is aware of the specifics of tmpfs (which overlay2 is not), or docker itself special-cases it (of which I'm not aware), then limiting the container memory will make no difference. However, the kernel could conceivably OOM your processes even if not all memory is exhausted. That's no longer docker/filesystem territory, that's tmpfs/memory management territory. Again, I think it's more likely the problem is with your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the current Docker version, there is a default limitation on the Docker container storage of 10 GB.
You can check the disk space that containers are using by running the following command:

> docker system df

It's also possible that the file your container is trying to access has access level restrictions. Try to make it available for docker or maybe everybody (chmod 777 file.txt).

Comment: It's a multi-process code where the files are generated by one process and consumed by another. So access restriction is not a problem.
BTW, I have no freaking which mount point the docker is using. Is there a way to figure out which parts of linux filesystem the docker is using for it's file access operations?

Comment: BTW, if docker manages it's own filesystem, how does it allocated this 10Gb to different directory structures in its filesystem?

Comment: Is it 10 Gb (gigabits) or 10 GB (gigabytes)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

Comment: darn, that was a typo. GB it is. Thanks for pointing it out.